# TableView made with RxSwift/RxCocoa glitches after a data change in the Variable it's bound to

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

The tableView that my variable is bound to jumps/glitches when the cell that I clicked on to trigger the data change.

Here is how the tableView and variable are bound:

```
variable.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items)
            { (tableView, row, dataForRow) in

}
```

When one of the buttons in the tableView is pressed I eventually update the variable's value like this:

```
variable.value = updatedData
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue you have to assign a new instance of DisposeBag to the cell's disposeBag variable when prepareForReuse() is called:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{

var disposeBag = DisposeBag() 


override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        disposeBag = DisposeBag() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard UITableView binder calls `reloadData` every time the observed array changes. The reloadData call doesn't animate and also resets the table view to the top. This is likely what you are seeing. Your choices are to make your own UITableViewDataSource object that only reloads the cells that actually changed, or use the RxDataSources cocoapod library that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The tableView wasn't being reset all the way to the top, and I also implemented the same functionality without RxSwift so that when the data changed I manually called reloadData() and the jump didn't occur then so I don't think calls to reloadData() are the problem. You may be right about using RxDataSources to resolve the issue but that solution would require me to have an additional dependency. I eventually fixed it by assigning a new instance of DisposeBag to the cell's diposeBag variable whenever prepareForReuse() was called.